# How do I parse info from this webpage..?

Tags: jquery, android, asp.net, parsing, html-parsing

I need to parse the weather information shown along with the corresponding images shown.
http://www.tportal.hr/vijesti/vrijeme/hrvatska7dana
How do i go about it?Seems the page seems to be using JQuery..?I need it for an android app I'm trying to work on.

Comment: Can you link the address to the site please?

Comment: The link has been provided.http://www.tportal.hr/vijesti/vrijeme/hrvatska7dana

Comment: It is not Jquery, the information you want to parse is plain HTML. BTW I am not very convinced you are allowed to use this information just like that. Search for `<div class="mData">` in the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something similar in the past. I used regular expressions to extract the data from a website because the HTML was poor and XML serialization was no option.

The website doesn't use jQuery to load the weather data. But the data is just in the page itself. The website always returns the same HTML with different data, so regular expressions are an option.

You could use a regular expression to extract the data from the .mData div on the page. I think it is easier to handle this on a server like the google appengine servers and return the data in json.

Another option is to ask them to create an rss feed or API for their service, if they do this your life will be a lot easier.